# checking for null using macro in C++ in template class

Tags: c++

I have following code I don't check in testFunc for null as we are checking in controlPtr class, instead I want to return. I am looking some thing like macro which I can add in template class so that I can have in function. (note: I am looking for options with out exceptions).

```
void AssertErrorHandler(const char* file_name,  unsigned line_number, const char* message) {
    std::cout << message << " in file " << file_name << " #" << line_number << std::endl << std::flush;
```

}

```
#define CONTROLASSERT(condition, msg)                 \
    if(!(condition)) {                              \
        std::ostringstream s;                       \
        s << msg;                                   \
        AssertErrorHandler(                    \
            __FILE__, __LINE__, s.str().c_str() );  \
    }

template <typename T>
class ControlPtr {
  public:

    explicit ControlPtr(T* p = NULL)
    : ptr_(p) {
    }

    T* Get() const {                        
        return ptr_;
    }

    ControlPtr<T>& operator=(T* p) {
        ptr_ = p;
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() const {                     
        CONTROLASSERT(ptr_ != NULL, "Attempt to use operator -> on NULL pointer.");
        return ptr_;
    }

    T& operator* () const { 
        CONTROLASSERT(ptr_ != NULL, "Attempt to use operator * on NULL pointer.");
        return *ptr_;
    }

private:
    T*  ptr_;
};

void testFunc() {

    int i = 10;
    ControlPtr<int> ptr(NULL); // Question: From here I should return. How can I modify controlPtr class above
                               // Do I use #define macro

    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;

    return;

}


int main( void )
{
    testFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never use `#define` macro...

Comment: throw an exception? That's what they are for... in your constructor check if the pointer is null, and if so throw...

Comment: I am looking for with out exceptions, any other alternative present

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't fully understand your requirement, but you *do* realise that you cannot simply return from your operator overloads (`->`, `*`) as these expect something valid to be returned - which is why the exception in constructor (or in your macro) is the safest approach...

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways out of `operator->`: return a non-NULL value, throw an exception, or `std::abort`. Since you've excluded the first two options, `std::abort` it is.